# Binding to nested property

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a class as o model:
The  class Flight and flightDetails are two classes defined in the proxy of the webservice:

```
public class FlightView
    {
        public FlightView()
        {
            FlightDetailsElement = new FlightDetails();
            Flight = new Flight();
            VisibleBoarding = false;
            VisibleCheckIn = false;
            Visibleluggage = false;
        }
        public Flight Flight;
        public FlightDetails FlightDetailsElement;
        private bool _visibleCheckIn;
        public bool VisibleCheckIn
        {
            get { return _visibleCheckIn; }
            set { _visibleCheckIn = value; }
        }
        private bool _visibleBoarding;
        public bool VisibleBoarding
        {
            get { return _visibleBoarding; }
            set { _visibleBoarding = value; }
        }
        private bool _visibleluggage;
        public bool Visibleluggage
        {
            get { return _visibleluggage; }
            set { _visibleluggage = value; }
        }
        private DateTime _refreshDate;
        public DateTime RefreshDate
        {
            get { return _refreshDate; }
            set { _refreshDate = value; }
        }
        private string _date;
        public string Date
        {
            get { return _date; }
            set { _date = value; }
        }
        private string _time;
        public string Time
        {
            get { return _time; }
            set { _time = value; }
        }

    }
```

in the codebehind i set the dataxontext of the grid:

```
 SelectedFlightView.FlightDetailsElement = e.Result;
        if(!(SelectedFlightView.FlightDetailsElement.IsArrival) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedFlightView.FlightDetailsElement.BoardingGate))
        SelectedFlightView.VisibleBoarding= true;
         if(!(SelectedFlightView.FlightDetailsElement.IsArrival) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedFlightView.FlightDetailsElement.CheckInArea))
        SelectedFlightView.VisibleCheckIn= true;
         if ((SelectedFlightView.FlightDetailsElement.IsArrival) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedFlightView.FlightDetailsElement.LuggageDelivery))
             SelectedFlightView.Visibleluggage = true;
         SelectedFlightView.RefreshDate = DateTime.Now;
         SelectedFlightView.Date = SelectedFlightView.RefreshDate.ToLongDateString();
         SelectedFlightView.Time = SelectedFlightView.RefreshDate.ToLongTimeString();
         ContentPanelDetails.DataContext = SelectedFlightView;
```

My problem is when i bind in the xaml:

```
 <TextBlock  Text="{Binding FlightDetailsElement.DepartureTime}"/>
```

I haven't the result, but when I bind

`<TextBlock  Text="{Binding Time}"/>` i have the result.

Any ideas please??

Regards

Comment: does FlightDetails has a property DepartureTime?

Comment: Yes and when i change  datacontext like this `ContentPanelDetails.DataContext = SelectedFlightView.FlightDetailsElement;` and i use `<TextBlock  Text="{Binding DepartureTime}"/>`  i have the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the binding to work, you need to use a public property. Currently, your `FlightDetailsElement` is a public field. To fix your problem, just declare it as a property:

```
public FlightDetails FlightDetailsElement { get; set; }
```